# How to sort by id in child element of a list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-selectors

Extremely new to code and only really trying basics.

I need to order this list by release date, selecting the class (.date) of the child element, and then using the id to sort by. bearing in mind the id of the li is used to sort by something else. i just cant figure out how to select the class of the child, and sort by the id of the child.

Here is the markup:

```
<button id="datereleased">Date Released</button>

<div id="sortcontainer">

 <li id="60">
  <h2>Some game</h2>
  <h2 class="date" id="2015">(2015)</h2>  
  <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>

 <li id="45">
  <h2>Some game</h2>
  <h2 class="date" id="2017">(2017)</h2>
  <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>

 <li id="80">
  <h2>Some game</h2>
  <h2 class="date" id="2013">(2013)</h2>
  <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>
</div>
```

and what i have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datereleased" ).click(function(){
        var lis = $('#sortcontainer').children('li').remove();    
        lis.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseInt($('.date > id', a)) >  parseInt($('.date > id', b));
        }); 
        $('#sortcontainer').append(lis);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance if anyone has any info

Comment: `$('.date > id', a)`  Uh, that `> id` part looks wrong.  There is an id on the date elements.  Are you trying get it?  Cause that's not a child element.  If so that would be like `$('.date', a).prop('id')`

Comment: If you're extremely new, you shouldn't be using jQuery. You ought to learn the native API so that you can understand how the DOM works. At some point, you'll probably realize that all those blog posts from 2011 telling you to use jQuery, really just aren't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the id attribute off the date for the sorting.

```js
$('#datereleased').on('click', function(){
  var $sortContainer = $('#sortcontainer');
  
  $sortContainer.append(
    $sortContainer.children().sort(function(a, b){
      return (
        parseInt($('.date', a).attr('id'), 10)
        -
        parseInt($('.date', b).attr('id'), 10)
      );
    }).get()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="datereleased">Date Released</button>

<div id="sortcontainer">
  <li id="60">
    <h2>Some game</h2>
    <h2 class="date" id="2015">(2015)</h2>
    <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>

  <li id="45">
    <h2>Some game</h2>
    <h2 class="date" id="2017">(2017)</h2>
    <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>

  <li id="80">
    <h2>Some game</h2>
    <h2 class="date" id="2013">(2013)</h2>
    <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou this worked a charm.  I realise the '>' symbol was selecting child elements. so trying the select the child of the date class. can i ask what the , 10 after the attr('id') is for? cheers

Comment: 10 is the base by which the parse operates.  So you could optionally parse a string into different formats, such as 16 parsing a string that contains a hex value.  The default is 10, I believe, but putting it there for clarity is just something I always do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your selector to target the `h2` elements that have a `date` class with an `id` instead of targeting elements with a tag named `id`.

Then you can sort that by performing subtraction on the values of the `id` attributes, and append the `li` ancestors.

This example doesn't use jQuery, and uses newer syntax, like arrow functions:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector("#datereleased").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var sc = document.querySelector("#sortcontainer");

      Array.from(sc.querySelectorAll('li > .date[id]'))
        .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
        .forEach(el => sc.appendChild(el.closest("li")));
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="datereleased">Date Released</button>

<div id="sortcontainer">

  <li id="60">
    <h2>Some game</h2>
    <h2 class="date" id="2015">(2015)</h2>
    <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>

  <li id="45">
    <h2>Some game</h2>
    <h2 class="date" id="2017">(2017)</h2>
    <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>

  <li id="80">
    <h2>Some game</h2>
    <h2 class="date" id="2013">(2013)</h2>
    <h3>45/100</h3>
  </li>
</div>
```